# 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xd7' in position 24: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, парсер

Работал запрос.Но вот что то случилось и выдает ошибку:
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xd7' in position 24: character maps to 
на этой строке спотыкается

```
with open('user1.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(response, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: поставил ensure_ascii=True заработало